# Solidify not working for a mesh

Tags: mesh

I have been working on an iron man helmet mesh, and I decided to add the solidify modifier, but it seems to do some strange stuff around the eyes. Any help?
[image]

Just to clear up, some zoomed in images:
[image]

Answer (score -2):

Never mind, just had to flip the normal's on some faces selectively